# Best way to secure AWS access in mobile app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

I have a mobile app, each user in this app needs to read and write to a DynamoDB table, also they need to read and write from an S3 bucket. There are no user accounts in this app, no user identity, no logging in. Every user needs the same access to the same DDB table and S3 bucket.

Currently I have this working with 'unauthenticated' cognito credentials that has its role constrained to the single DynamoDB table and single S3 bucket. This seems Okay to me. But if someone finds out my identityPoolId then they can basically make any edits to my S3 bucket and DDB table. Is it sufficient to just rely on hiding the identityPoolId in the mobile app somehow?

Also relying on cognito seems maybe overkill since users don't actually have any identity in my app. Right now it just generates a new 'unauthenticated' cognito credential every time the app opens. Seems like that'd waste alot of AWS resource unnecessarily because I would just be getting thousands of unauthenticated cognito users generated each time a user opens the app. Is that how that should work or am I missing something there?

But then I was also reading about using 'temporary security credentials' which relies on AccessKeyId, SecretAccessKey and SessionToken:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_use-resources.html
Which this does not need any cognito resources at all. Is this the more appropriate thing to use in my case? Is it sufficient security to just hide that key, secret and token in my codebase and rely on that?

Comment: No, "hiding" the id or key is not sufficient, that is "security by obscurity".

Comment: So then how are you supposed to secure the identitypoolid or the secret keys?

Comment: you do not hide them, basically, at least not as a primary part of your security. You need to properly restrict what a user can do with that id / with credentials for any role managed by it. E.g. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_dynamodb_items.html and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_s3_cognito-bucket.html

Comment: I have my unauthenticated cognito role constrained to just the one ddb table and the one S3 bucket with only the operations they should be able to do. Still though, if someone gets my identitypoolid they could then just start uploading a bunch of arbitrary files though?